# ImportError: cannot import X from the file that has if __name__ == "__main__". Any solutions without delete if __name__ == "__main__"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-import

I have 2 files `n1711_001_insilico` and `n1711_002_insilico` in the same folder. I want two variables (`mzdf` which is `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`, and `charge` is`'int'`) from the first file so I do `import` at the top of the second file:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from n1711_001_insilico import mzdf, charge
```

I got `ImportError: cannot import name mzdf`(as well as for `charge`). In the first file, I explicitly return both `mzdf` and `charge` from the function and call them like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mzdf, charge = CALC(peptides_report, aa_dict, charge_from=1, charge_to=6)
```

Update: from the comment I now know the issue comes from `if __name__ == "__main__":` in the first file. Any ways that I can fix this without deleting `if __name__ == "__main__"`?

Comment: Did you create a file name as `__init__.py` on the same directory with `n1711_001_insilico.py`?

Comment: @FrankAK No I don't. Should I have it?

Comment: Try it. Maybe help.

Comment: Your import statement won't work with `if __name__ == "__main__":` since you aren't calling **that** script as `__main__`

Comment: @FrankAK I still got same error after creating blank `__init__.py` in the same directory.

Comment: Could you please update your question with your directory structure?

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry, but I don't really understand. May you explain a bit more? You mean now my second file which is main now cannot have the first one?

Comment: @FrankAK Both two files are in the same folder. I updated the question.

Comment: Anything in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard won't run when the file is imported as a module. That's the whole point of `if __name__ == "__main__"`.

Comment: Oh I got it! Then the first file always cannot have `if __name__ == "__main__"` or it has any alternative solution?

Comment: What's wrong with just calling `CALC()` yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file you are trying to import, you have this statement:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mzdf, charge = CALC(peptides_report, aa_dict, charge_from=1, charge_to=6)
```

This means that only if the file is directly executed in the command line, for example with `python n1711_001_insilico.py` will the command `CALC` actually run and be executed, and this is the function that is setting the two variables `mzdf` and `charge`.

In other words, only when you run the file directly with `python n1711_001_insilico.py` do these two variables exist, when you import it, Python will not run that function.

This is by design; once you import the file, the variable `__name__` points to the name of the file, so the condition fails.

Now, to solve this problem you will have to run the `CALC` function when you import the file, and get your own copy of the result:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from n1711_001_insilico import peptides_report, aa_dict, CALC

mzdf, charge = CALC(peptides_report, aa_dict, charge_form=1, charge_to=6)
```